# Partition into c and 1-c

Tags: partition-problem

> Let $c\in(0,1/2]$ be a constant. Given a set of positive integers with sum $S$, is there a partition into two subsets such that both subsets have sum at least $cS$?

If $c=1/2$, this is the famous [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) which is NP-complete. What is known about the complexity for other values of $c$?

Comment: It is NP-hard for every fixed constant $c$ with $0<c<1/2$.

Comment: @Gamow Thanks. Could you please give a reference?

Comment: @Gamow This is incorrect, according to [Tom van der Zanden's answer on CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/110914/9550).